# RESTful API how to check that sevarel items exists

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using the mobile application to work with Yii2 RESTful API. In my mobile app I do have a shopping cart with items. So the idea is where user is opening a shopping cart to check that products are still available and have not been sold. So I was thinking to get list of product's id and send a request to RESTful API to check that all of them is fine. If some of them sold I should get back a changed list od products. So far I request my items using this link https://api.website.com/products?product_id=969

What is the good approach to solve this issue? Or in my mobile app I have to create a loop to check each product by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A usual practice for use use case you describe is to create an endpoint that accepts a list of IDs, separated by some character (comma, semicolon, etc). For example:

```
https://api.website.com/products?product_ids=969,970,971
```

In that action you'd loop over each individual ID in `product_ids`.